# Mapbox Gl JS: Can't update feature property with setFeatureState

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to create a web app that renders circles on a map. If the `numUsers` property is >= 1, the circle is green and if the `numUsers` property is 0, the circle is red (the default value is 0).

Below is the structure of my data source:

```
{ 
    "type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[ 
        { 
            "type": "Feature",
            "id": 0,
            "geometry":{ 
                "type":"Point",
                "coordinates":[ 
                    1.49129,
                    42.46372
                ]
            },
            "properties": { 
                "numUsers":0
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

All the circles are initially rendered as red, which is what I want, because the `numUsers` property of each circle is initially set to 0. However, I want to change one of the circles to be green by setting the numUsers property to 1. I'm trying to use `setFeatureState`, but it **doesn't** change the circle's color to green:

```
map.setFeatureState({source: "cities", id : 0}, {numUsers : 1});
```

Below is my rendering JS code:

```
map.on('style.load', function (e) {
    map.addSource('cities', {
        "type": "geojson",
        "data": "cities.geojson",
        "cluster": true,
        "clusterMaxZoom": 14,
        "clusterRadius": 80
    });

    map.addLayer({
        "id": "cities",
        "type": "circle",
        "source": "cities",
        "paint": {
            "circle-color": { 
                property: 'numUsers',
                stops: [
                    [0, '#ff6666'],
                    [1, '#33ff33']
                ]
            }
        }
    }, 'settlement-label');
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use "feature-state"<sup>[1]</sup> expression to get the state that was set using `setFeatureState` and use "case" expression to switch through state values and set desired color.

Here's the gist of it:

```js
// update after 2 seconds
setTimeout(() => {
  map.setFeatureState({ id: 0, source: "geom" }, { numUsers: 1 });
  map.setFeatureState({ id: 1, source: "geom" }, { numUsers: 2 });
}, 2000);

map.addLayer({
  id: "geom",
  type: "circle",
  paint: {
    "circle-color": [
      "case",
         ["==", ["feature-state", "numUsers"], 1], "blue",
         ["==", ["feature-state", "numUsers"], 2], "green",
         "red"
       ],
       "circle-radius": 4
  },
  source: { /* ... source */ }
});
```

Code pen with a working map: https://codepen.io/manishraj/full/YzKeBwv

[1] https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-feature-state

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can use those kinds of function expressions with feature states, per https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#other-function.

Instead you should be able to use a `match` expression https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-match with `["feature-state", "numUsers"]` to get the feature state in an expression, https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-feature-state